# py.test can't import my module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, pytest

I am struggeling getting a python import right. What I want to achieve is to have a module with several source files and a test folder with unit tests.

No matter what I do, I can't get py.test-3 to execute my tests. My directory layout looks like this:

```
.
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── testclass.py
└── tests
    └── test_testclass.py
```

The __init__.py file looks like this:

```
__all__ = ['testclass']
```

The testclass.py file looks like this:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1
```

And my unit test like this:

```
import pytest
from module import TestClass

def test_test_class():
    tc = TestClass()
    assert(tc.id==1)
```

No matter how I call py.test-3 I will end up with a:

```
E   ImportError: No module named 'module'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, unless you change the `tests/test_testclass.py`, you need to change `module/__init__.py` as follow:

```
from .testclass import TestClass

__all__ = ['TestClass']
```

And, when you run py.test set [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to let the interpreter know when to find modules:

```
PYTHONPATH=. py.test
```

Comment: This works for me! Would it be the pythonic way of doing it? Still struggeling how a library layout should look like best.

Comment: @Fabian, I think so. It does not require you to change the test code at least.

Comment: Wow I just saw your video. Thanks for the effort! Your dedication is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I would put in a header of testfile the path execution for pytest:

example:

```
import os, sys                                                                  
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))
```

With this I could know the path of any subfolder in my (test) project

Comment: I am not a real fan of this solution since I would have to repeat it in any test file which goes against the DRY principle.

Comment: This can be put in the "\__init\__.py" of the tests/ folder and you wouldn't need to repeat it for the entire directory.